# Change namespace/filesystem folder names in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, namespaces, refactoring

I'm trying to change a namespace in Visual Studio.

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
GameAlpha/
         GameAlpha.sln
         GameAlphaRelease/
         GameAlphaTest/
         GameAlphaLevelEditor/
```

These include namespaces like `GameAlphaRelease`. I want to change all this to `GameBetaRelease`.

Before this process, it built fine.

First, I changed the solution and project files from Alpha to Beta. Then, I did a "find-replace-all" on the namespace. Finally, I went through the properties of each project and changed the "Assembly Name" and "Default Namespace" to the appropriate Beta title.

However, now the solution does not build. The error is:

> GameAlpha.accessor: The reference to 'GameAlpha.exe' was not found in
>   the list of this projects references.
>   (Project: GameBetaTest)

What am I doing wrong? If I remove project GameBetaTest, the solution builds just fine.

Also, what is the preferable way to change the names of the folders in the file system?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but I'd never use project names (especially interim names and namespaces) to indicate the build of a piece of software.  That's what version numbers and version descriptions are for.

Comment: Given the difficulty of changing this, I am suspecting that you are correct in that tendency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps normally work for me:

- Use the standard project rename (this renames the project, but not the Project Directory). If you want to change the directory as well, close down the solution, rename the directory, open the solution, remove the old project (which is now unavailable) and add the project from the new location.
- For each project for which it applies, remove and re-add references to other projects in the solution if there are any inter-project dependencies.
- Adjust the project properties for each changed project.
- Verify/adjust build scripts.
- Verify/adjust the build order.
- Clean and rebuild all.

If you do a package/class rename, make sure you do it separately (before, while everything is "still working") so that VS will update the internals as required. YMMV and there are some issues with files "linked" between projects.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the physical project directory

Note: The physical path property is recorded in the .sln file so you cannot just rename the folder in Explorer.

a. Close the solution and the IDE

b. In Explorer: Change the directory name to the new name.

c. In Explorer:  Open the .sln file with a text editor.

c. Change the directory name to the new name and save.

d. Restart the IDE and open the solution from the File, Recent Files menu if it doesn't start automatically.

e. Click on the Project folder of the Solution Explorer and check the path property in the properties at the bottom. It will now be referencing to the new project folder.

[Here I found it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4133fb7-57e1-44f2-a319-a63e7921ff0a/how-to-rename-assemblies-and-project-folders?forum=csharpide)